# Send pylint warning to bottom of list

Tags: python

When I'm using `pylint-mode` for a big refactor, I quite frequently want to banish lower-priority errors to the bottom of the buffer. Currently I have to skip the same errors ever time I refresh the buffer.

Is there a way to do this?